# Number of asked questions in Stack Overflow's Tags page

Tags: discussion, support, tags

In the [Tags page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) of Stack Overflow that the number of asked questions is not updated Or just not renitialized (see an example below).

What I knew before, is that a [SE "day"](http://What%20is%20an%20SE%20%E2%80%9Cday%E2%80%9D?%20When%20does%20each%20day%20start?) starts at 00:00 UTC time, is that the same logic used for the number of asked questions?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That particular count does not reset at the new UTC day. If you hover over it, you'll get a tooltip that reads:

> 602 questions tagged java in the last 24 hours

Those two numbers are running totals over the past 24 hours and 7 days, respectively. They increase and decrease as new questions get asked and as questions pass the timeframes.